# Creating longer path with routes and page controller in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

I want to create a longer url or route like the following url: www.allrecipes.com/recipe/84783/poblano-chicken-salad/. Mine would be website.test/shoes/shoe1.

For that I created a controller with a function that looks like this:

```
public function shoes() {
    return view('pages.shoes');
}
```

And for my route I have:

```
Route::get('/shoes', 'PagesController@shoes');
```

Now, I'd like to append shoes1 to shoes. I tried to do:

```
Route::get('/shoes/shoe1', 'PagesController@shoes');
```

but this did not work.

I am not sure if I can create another function in my Controller and make it work with my shoes() function. I also tried using Route Groups as shown in the documentation but I honestly do not think what they have there is helping my case. Perhaps [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes) might work?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no reason why this shouldn't work. Please make sure you do not have routes cached by using `php artisan route:clear`.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

All I had to do was to create a function for shoe1 in my controller and create a route like so: `Route::get('/shoes/shoe1', 'PagesController@shoe1')->name('clothing.shoe1');`